# How to Pinch Zoom Images Like Instagram or Facebook?

Tags: android, imageview, pinchzoom

Anyone know's how to pinch Zoom Imageview Like Instagram feed or Facebook post. TIA. tried to search but no one lib or post giving exact information.

Comment: Did you really search? https://github.com/stfalcon-studio/FrescoImageViewer

Comment: @Jaeger work like charm. thanx a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way the question asked is very bad. 
take a look at [WRITING THE PERFECT QUESTION - JON SKEET](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

You could spend 10 seconds and just [google it](https://www.google.ge/search?q=pinch+zoom+android).

Anyway, zooming `ImageView` is not a big deal. see those libraries

- https://github.com/stfalcon-studio/FrescoImageViewer
- https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView

Comment: Thanx, a lot @tatocaster. FrescoImageview works fine.